# How to separate out a JSON Object for a reusable React table component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an object, as seen below:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dan",
  "icon": "",
  "stat_1": 1.2,
  "stat_2": 2.5,
  "stat_3": 4.1,
  "stat_4": 1,
  "stat_5": 12,
  "critical_hit": true,
  "g_combo": [],
  "a_combo": [],
  "t_combo": [],
}
```

My goal is to be able to loop over this object (exclude the arrays) and create a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
|  Character Stats for Dan  |
+---------------------------+
|   ID    | 1               |
+---------+-----------------+
|   NAME  | Dan             |
+---------+-----------------+
|   ICON  | {icon img}      |
+---------+-----------------+
...etc..
```

Basically, create a table that uses the `Object Key` as the left column, and the `Object Value` for the right.

So far, this is what I have tried, but keep running into errors with React:

```
export default function SpecSheet(props) {
  const character = props.CharacterData;
  const characterInfo = Object.entries(character);

return (
  characterInfo.map((item, index)=> (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{item[0]}</td>
      <td>{item[1]}</td>
    </tr>
  });

))
)
```

and then I will call it on my file like this:

`<SpecSheet CharacterData={data} />`

{data} is the reference to my JSON file.

---

My problem:

This seems to generate exactly what i'm looking for in the console, except for the fact that it doesn't filter the arrays out, and the Table doesn't seem to generate on the page. The only error I;m getting is

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`, but I'm providing an index on my `tr` element.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried something like this:

```js
const data = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dan",
  "icon": "",
  "stat_1": 1.2,
  "stat_2": 2.5,
  "stat_3": 4.1,
  "stat_4": 1,
  "stat_5": 12,
  "critical_hit": true,
  "g_combo": [],
  "a_combo": [],
  "t_combo": [],
};

function SpecSheet(props) {
  const character = props.CharacterData;
  const characterInfo = 
    Object.entries(character)
      .filter(([key,val]) => !Array.isArray(val));

  return (
    characterInfo.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={`${character.id}-${item[0]}`}>
          <td>{item[0]}</td>
          <td>{item[1]}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    )
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<SpecSheet CharacterData={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

This will filter out any values that are an array, and uses the character's (hopefully) unique `id` with the property as the key for each `<tr/<}>`

Comment: This seems to generate what I'm looking for in the console, but still am running into the table not building :/

Comment: Can you share more of the code responsible for displaying the rest of the table?

Comment: It's just that function, and then it gets imported to the page and called as 
`<SpecSheet CharacterData={data} />`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working snippet and outputs as expected. Something else in your code may be causing the issues

Comment: Ah, got it working with that edit, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your lowest code block, you have an extra closed curly brace that doesn't belong.

Try using Object.keys(danObj). This will create an array of the keys in your Object. So assuming I get to renamek your object to danObj, you can do something like this:

```
const tableRows = Object.keys(danObj)
    // Don't run this code on your arrays
    .filter(obj => !Array.isArray(danObj[obj]))
    .map(stat => (
        <tr key={stat}>
            <td>{stat}</td>
            <td>{danObj[stat]}</td>
        </tr>
    )
```

Info on Object.keys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys